# Show different divs from different buttons with same class

Tags: javascript

I have (currently) three buttons

```
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 1</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 2</button></p>
<p><button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 3</button></p>
```

With these buttons, i want to show different menus/overlays. the overlays looks like this:

```
        <!-- Menu1 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
    <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a class="menuitem2">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- Menu2 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
    <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a class="menuitem2">Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
        <!-- Menu3 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
    <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a class="menuitem2">Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The JS for this is:

```
(function() {
        var triggerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        }
    }


for (var i = 0; i < triggerButtons.length; i++) {
    triggerButtons[i].addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
}
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

My problem is that it is only menu1 that is showing. The script is otherwise working, but menu2 and menu3 is not showing.

Im thinking that is has to be something missing with `function toggleOverlay`. Maybe a $(this) or something (sorry my JS is not what it used to be). Im looping through `triggerButtons` and from google chrome dev I get the "right" button clicked (i think, hard to tell).

Expected result:
If I press button 3 in order, menu 3 show. If i press button 2 i should see menu 2, and so on.

Comment: Where is `classie` coming from?

Comment: @agmcleod from https://github.com/codrops/FullscreenOverlayStyles/blob/master/js/classie.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will fix your issue. I've added red and blue css classes for close and open respectively, to be visible.

```js
(function() {
  var triggerButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger-overlay'),
    overlay = document.querySelectorAll('div.overlay');
  var closeButtons = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < overlay.length; i++) {
    var closeBttn = overlay[i].querySelector('button.overlay-close');
    closeButtons.push(closeBttn);
  }

  transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
      'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
    support = {
      transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
    };

  function toggleOverlay(overlay) {
    if (classie.has(overlay, 'open')) {
      classie.remove(overlay, 'open');
      classie.add(overlay, 'close');
      var onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.transitions) {
          if (ev.propertyName !== 'visibility') return;
          this.removeEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
        }
        classie.remove(overlay, 'close');
      };
      if (support.transitions) {
        overlay.addEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
      } else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
      }
    } else {
      classie.add(overlay, 'open');
      classie.remove(overlay, 'close');
    }
  }


  for (var i = 0; i < triggerButtons.length; i++) {
    triggerButtons[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        toggleOverlay(overlay[i])
      };
    })(i));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < closeButtons.length; i++) {
    closeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        toggleOverlay(overlay[i])
      };
    })(i));
  }
})();
```

```css
.overlay.close {
  background-color: red;
}
.overlay.open {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classie/1.0.1/classie.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 1</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 2</button>
</p>
<p>
  <button class="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay 3</button>
</p>

<!-- Menu1 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc close">
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem2">Item2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- Menu2 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc close">
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem2">Item1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<!-- Menu3 -->
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc close">
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menuitem1">Menu3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="menuitem2">Item1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

querySelectorAll should have been used instead on querySelector for getting all the overlays. And since each overlay contains a close button I iterated over them to add event listeners for clicking. Also I used closure to keep the index of button.

Your toggleOverlay has some logic problems. Which isn't in the scope of the question. So I didn't fix it.

**Update**
I fixed the toggleOverlay issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use the different id for the div and perform the operation using the ID

Comment: could you please elaborate how to do that?